# Getting the name of each field in JSON

Tags: json, parsing, grails

I'm trying to parse a random JSON file in Grails.

First I need to get the name of each field

For example, given below JSON file,

```
{
    "abbreviation": "EX",
    "guid": "1209812-1l2kj1j-fwefoj9283jf-ae",
    "metadata": {
      "dataOrigin": "Example"
    },
    "rooms": 
    [
    ],
    "site": {
      "guid": "1209812-1l2kj1j-fwefoj9283jf-ae"
    },
    "title": "Example!!"
}
```

I want to find out the structure of the JSON file(lists of keys maybe), for example I want to save the list of keys such as 'abbreviation', 'guid', 'metadata', 'rooms', 'site', 'title' from this JSON file.

How would I do this?

(We need the name of the keys in order to get the value of that key, so with a arbitrarily structured JSON file I need to find out the keys first)

Comment: `new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(path to the json file).keySet()` is what you are looking for I assume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what dmahaptro commented, I figured out how to get all the keys within a JSON object.

Here is a simple sample code I wrote to test it

```
String jsonFile = new JsonSlurper().parseText(new URL(path to the json file).text)
JSONArray jsonParse = new JSONArray(jsonFile)

int len = jsonParse.length()
def names = []
def keys = []
(0..len-1).each {
    JSONObject val = jsonParse.getJSONObject(it)
    int numKeys = val.length()
    names = val.names()
    keys = val.keySet()
    (0..numKeys-1).each {
        def field = names[it]
        println field +" : " + val."${field}"
    }
}
```

This will print the key:value pair given a JSON file.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code

```
def filePath = "JSONFILE.json"
def text = new File(filePath).getText()
def json = JSON.parse(text)                     
def jsonKeys = json.collect{it.key}
println(jsonKeys)
```

This will print all json keys